# Crash Instantiating System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

We're seeing a crash when instantiating an instance of the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` class in a C# library.  The crash occurs in the constructor, when it tries to add a duplicate key to a dictionary.  I've included a stack trace below.

This crash is only occurring on one machine, and repairing our installation of .NET 3.5 didn't help.  Has anyone else seen any similar issues?

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'mainbuild'  Key being added: 'mainbuild'"
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
       at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
       at System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary.Add(String key, String value)
       at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
       at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
       at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String trueArgs)
       at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
       at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
       at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
       at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
       at OurTools.Tools.Common.XML.DataAccess`1.DeserializeFromXml(String strFilePath) in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurTools.Tools.Common\OurTools.Tools.Common\XML\DataAcess.cs:line 100
       at OurTools.Tools.Common.ProjectFileManager.GetProjectInfoModel() in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurTools.Tools.Common\OurTools.Tools.Common\ProjectFileManager.cs:line 252
       at OurTools.Tools.Common.ProjectFileManager.GetAvailableCultures() in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurTools.Tools.Common\OurTools.Tools.Common\ProjectFileManager.cs:line 299
       at OurAppLib.GeneratorOptions.DefaultCultures() in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurApp\OurAppLib\GeneratorOptions.cs:line 192
       at OurAppLib.GeneratorOptions.ReadCulturesFromArgs(List`1 arglist, String& errormsg) in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurApp\OurAppLib\GeneratorOptions.cs:line 358
       at OurAppLib.GeneratorOptions.ReadFromArgs(String[] args, String& errormsg) in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurApp\OurAppLib\GeneratorOptions.cs:line 261
       at OurApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\AutomatedBuild\projects\1.0\OurApp\OurApp\Program.cs:line 76`print("code sample");`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this link, which explains the issue:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/4476f044-bab9-492d-bb94-4e0960bd2d26

A quick summary: When serializing, the object makes a dictionary out of all environment variables, but appears to run a ToLower() on all entries.  So, if you have two environment variables that are the same except for casing, you'll get a crash.

This is only going to be a problem when running from inside a system like cygwin which enforces case sensitivity for variables.  In our case, we're using make.

There are a couple solutions, but they all revolve around making sure that your environment doesn't have any duplicated variables when your c# app runs.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem (also from within Cygwin), so your answer was VERY helpful!

Comment: Glad I could save you some time.  I was banging my head against the wall for a while trying to figure this one out.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in a recent version of the .Net runtime, for some value of "recent" between 4.0 and 4.7.  It still exists in the 2.0-3.5 runtime.